# Create widget select type field based on 3rd party API response

Tags: apostrophe-cms

We started to develop a site in Apostrophe CMS based on a 3rd party API and stuck on the following issue:

- we need a widget which has a select (on admin side).
- the options from it are generated based on an API response.
- the Admin user will select an option when he/she sets up the widget parameters (server side).
- based on this selection we will call another API, and based on that response will generate some HTML (client side; images, texts, etc.)

The scenario is the following: the admin chooses a product from a list and on the front-end we will show information based on that selection.

```
const request = require( 'request-promise' );

module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    label: 'Preloaded list widget',
    addFields: [
        {
            label: 'Product',
            name: 'product',
            type: 'select',
            required: true,
            choices: "getChoices"
        }
    ],

    getChoices: async function( req )
    {
        const products = await request( {
            uri: "http://API_for_product_list",
            json: true
        } );

        var choiceList = [];
        for( idx = 0; idx < products.totalRecords; idx++ )
        {
            var option =
            {
                label: products.items[ idx ].label,
                value: products.items[ idx ].value
            };

            choiceList.push( option );
        }

        return choiceList;
    }
};
```

When I start the application i got the following warning:
"widget type preloadedlist, field name product:
When using showFields, field.choices must be an array"
And the list shows empty. The getChoices function is never called.

I'm missing something but I don't know what. We did everything according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach your `getChoices` function to the module itself so that it can be referenced later.

```
const request = require('request-promise');

module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Preloaded list widget',
  addFields: [{
    label: 'Product',
    name: 'product',
    type: 'select',
    required: true,
    choices: 'getChoices'
  }],
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.getChoices = async function (req) {
      const products = await request({
        uri: "http://API_for_product_list",
        json: true
      });

      var choiceList = [];
      for (idx = 0; idx < products.totalRecords; idx++) {
        var option = {
          label: products.items[idx].label,
          value: products.items[idx].value
        };

        choiceList.push(option);
      }
      return choiceList;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the results are the same. I also get the same waning and the product select is empty.

Comment: I'm in a new sandbox with a fresh install of apostrophe 2.90.0 and this code works. You've restarted the app since restructuring? Can you console out the choices list you're returning? Warnings concerned with `field.choices must be an array` are being checked to see if `field.choices` is an array, which would make me think you're passing something else. If the function is not actually running you should get the much harsher error `self.apos.modules[field.moduleName][field.choices] is not a function`. However, i can't get your specific error to come back no matter what I pass as choices..

Comment: Yes, I am restarting the app every time a restart is needed. The issue was I had an older version: 2.89.0. After update everything works just fine. Thanks.